# Dit-on mieux « Peux-tu passer à l’épicerie acheter/prendre du lait » ou « Peux-tu passer à l’épicerie pour acheter/prendre du lait »?

Tags: choix-de-mot, prépositions, expressions-idiomatiques, formulation-idiomatique, formulation

Peux-tu passer en chemin à l’épicerie

…acheter/prendre du lait.

…pour acheter/prendre du lait.

Laquelle est la plus idiomatique?

N’hésitez pas à me présenter d’autres formulations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Tu peux prendre du lait à l'épicerie ?*

*Tu peux passer à l'épicerie pour prendre du lait ?*

*En revenant, tu peux faire un saut à l'épicerie et m'acheter une bouteille de lait ?*

Comment: Et qu’en est-il de « Tu peux passer à l’épicerie prendre du lait »?

Comment: C'est bien sûr possible mais il me semble que sans la préposition, l'ordre inverse est plus courant.

Comment: C’est à dire « Tu peux passer prendre du lait à l’épicerie »?

Comment: Je n’ai pas indiqué ce détail, mais je cherche la phrase qui serait la plus idiomatique.

Comment: Il y a des quantités de phrases idiomatiques pour dire ça. *En revenant, tu peux faire un saut à l'épicerie et me ramener une bouteille de lait ?*

Comment: Je crois qu’il faudrait plutôt dire dans ton exemple « rapporter une bouteille de lait » car il s’agit d’un objet et non d’un être animé. Sinon tout est AOK.

Comment: Mais à l’oral où il y a peu de place à la réflexion, où tout doit se dire spontanément, il doit être d’usage de confondre « rapporter » et « ramener » sans que cela soit choquant.

Comment: Oui. C'est à peu près ce que j'étais en train de répondre à l'instant. Cette nuance est en train de disparaître. *Ramène-moi quelque chose* s'entend plus que *rapporte-moi quelque chose* qui est plus réservé à quelque chose qui aurait été emprunté, ce qui ne marche pas avec une bouteille de lait.

Answer (score 0):

Personnellement, la formulation sans préposition « […] passer à l’épicerie acheter/prendre […] » me parait plus idiomatique.

Comment: » Il lui écrivit de bien vouloir passer à son bureau pour prendre connaissance d’anciens papiers trouvés dans une maison de la rue de la Harpe »  Zola

Comment: @Olivier Pertinent, merci.

Answer (score 0):

Les deux me paraissent idiomatiques même si la présence d'*en chemin* peut selon la position et le cas venir perturber un bloc sémantique et entraver une compréhension fluide.

Ok :

> Tu peux passer à l'épicerie pour acheter ... ?
>
> Tu peux passer acheter ... à l'épicerie ?
>
> Tu peux passer à l'épicerie acheter ... ?

Plus brouillon/désarticulé :

> Tu peux passer acheter ... en chemin à l'épicerie ?